# partially sorting in decending order

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

We have to partially sort an array in descending order.

I know std::partial_sort but it does it in ascending order.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort.

Is their any other such function that can do so or any fast algorithm to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second overload in the reference you linked to takes a Comparer – pass in an instance of [`std::greater<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

Answer (score 1):

According to your link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort,
another definition of partial_sort allows you to include a comparator.

Just include a comparator with the order of the elements reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the second form of the function and pass the correct comparator. Eg. `std::greater` might be a good tip.